# Multiple user authentication for TJWS for CouchBase Lite Listener

Tags: java, android, rest, couchbase, tjws

I'm using this implementation to provide REST to internal CouchBase Lite instance on Android device.

```
https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-lite-android-liteserv
```

Unfortunately, it does not support authentications of any form. I need to be able to specify user/password pairs that can connect to the underlying TJWS web server that provides REST interface via HTTP.

I'm struggling in finding how this can be done at all. Looks like TJWS supports HTTP BASIC AUTH, but I cannot find more on making a class that can return success / failure for given user/pass pairs.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic Auth support is currently in the works:

https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-java-listener/issues/35